# Exception Handling in EF when Try To Delete Not Cascaded Entity

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

assume that there are two entity:

```
public class Category
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Product> Products { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string CategoryId { get; set; }
    public string Caption { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }

    public virtual Category Category { get; set; }
}
```

and the cascade delete are not allowed.

```
public class ProductMap : EntityTypeConfiguration<Product>
{
    public ProductMap()
    {
        // Primary Key
        this.HasKey(t => t.Id);

        // Properties
        this.Property(t => t.Caption)
            .IsRequired()
            .HasMaxLength(50);

        // Table & Column Mappings
        this.ToTable("Products");
        this.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("Id");
        this.Property(t => t.Caption).HasColumnName("Caption");

        // Relationships
        this.HasRequired(t => t.Category)
            .WithMany(t => t.Products)
            .HasForeignKey(d => d.CategoryId)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

so when i want to delete a category that some products related to it, and DbUpdateException accurred. and in error message of exception write :

```
{"The DELETE statement conflicted with the REFERENCE constraint \"FK_dbo.Products_dbo.Categories_CategoryId\". The conflict occurred in database \"TestDb\", table \"dbo.Products\", column 'CategoryId'.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}
```

there are any error code to find out that when accurred DbUpdateException this is related to deleting dont cascade records?
i know sql server return error number 547 but what about entity framework?

Comment: What entity are you applying the fluent api to?  What is `this`?  Are you using Code First, Model First, or Database first?

Comment: @Justin, please review this post again, i edit post at now, i am using code first

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can get the original `SqlException` that is the cause of the Entity Framework specific exception.

That one contains all sorts of useful information, like the `Number` property containing the Sql Server error code.

This should do the trick:

```
try
{
    tc.SaveChanges();
}
catch (DbUpdateException ex)
{
    var sqlException = ex.GetBaseException() as SqlException;

    if (sqlException != null)
    {
        var number = sqlException.Number;

        if (number == 547)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Must delete products before deleting category");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Amazing very helpful. Can we get the same exception get in normal Exception object?